# What does a Head do in html?

Tags: html, frontend

I'm working on a HTML project. And I'm new to HTML and CSS, I'm happy with what I have now. So my question is: What does a `<head>` do in a HTML code.
Thanks already cheers.

Comment: This is a very very basic question about HTML. I can only suggest you to read a good handbook or tutorial about HTML. Or just search the internet for "HTML <head>"

Answer (score 2):

### Description:

The `<head>` element is a container for [metadata](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp) (data about data) and is placed between the `<html>` tag and the `<body>` tag. HTML metadata is data about the HTML document. Metadata is not displayed. Metadata typically define the document title, character set, styles, links, scripts, and other meta information.

The following tags describe metadata: `<title>`, `<style>`, `<meta>`, `<link>`, `<script>`, and `<base>`:

**Tag   Description:**

`<head>`    Defines information about the document.

`<title>`   Defines the title of a document.

`<base>`    Defines a default address or a default target for all links on a page.

`<link>`
Defines the relationship between a document and an external resource.

`<meta>`    Defines [metadata](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp) about an HTML document.

`<script>`  Defines a client-side script.

`<style`>   Defines style information for a document.

---

### Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <head>
      <title>Page Title</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      The content of the document......
   </body>

</html>
```

---

### Source:

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_head.asp

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific? I'm guessing you mean the head element.

According to MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element) the head element is used for the following:

> The HTML  element provides general information (metadata) about
>   the document, including its title and links to its scripts and style
>   sheets.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It works like your head.
Peoples can distinguishes others with their head, not body.
Your eye, voice from your tongue, your face, and so on.

Web browsers will distinguishes the title of the page, and linked assets files(css, js and images) and meta tags...
It makes the browser how to display the body part.

Hope it helps!
Thank you.